# Multithread error

Tags: c++, multithreading

I typed the following code into CodeLite (Linux) and it gave me the error below:

:18:62: error: invalid conversion from ‘void* (*)()’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ [-fpermissive]

//CODE HERE///

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

    void *functionC();
    pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    int  counter = 0;

    main()
    {
       int rc1, rc2;
       pthread_t thread1, thread2;

       /* Create independent threads each of which will execute functionC */

       if( (rc1=pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, &functionC, NULL)) )
       {
          printf("Thread creation failed: %d\n", rc1);
       }

       if( (rc2=pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, &functionC, NULL)) )
       {
          printf("Thread creation failed: %d\n", rc2);
       }

       /* Wait till threads are complete before main continues. Unless we  */
       /* wait we run the risk of executing an exit which will terminate   */
       /* the process and all threads before the threads have completed.   */

       pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
       pthread_join( thread2, NULL);

       exit(0);
    }

    void *functionC()
    {
       pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 );
       counter++;
       printf("Counter value: %d\n",counter);
       pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );
    }
```

Could anyone please explain to me why i got this error and how to correct it

Thankz for your answers and comments

Answer (score 4):

You have a type mismatch. `pthread_create` expects a function pointer of type `void *(*func_name)(void*)`. But you gave it a `void *functionC()`, which is not the same.

Change your function to this:

```
void* functionC(void*)
{
   pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 );
   counter++;
   printf("Counter value: %d\n",counter);
   pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );

   return NULL;
}
```

And you will also need to change your prototype as well:

```
void* functionC(void*);
```

Comment: Yup, his prototype declaration is wrong btw, probably ought to mention that.

Comment: Where is the error? Also, get rid of the `&` from your `&functionC`. So just use `functionC`. (I'm not sure if this is the error.)

Comment: That's strange. You definitely included `<pthread.h>`. Just it complain about any of the other pthread functions?

Comment: yes, it also gives a this error:undefined reference to `pthread_create'

Comment: Oh... It's a linker error. Add `-lpthread` to the compile options.

Comment: could you please tell me how to add -1pthread to the compile options

Comment: I'm not familiar with CodeLite, but I'm sure you can google around for how to to that.